# View Markdown stream or watched file on OS/X

Tags: macos, markdown

While I've used various markdown editors, I'm having this problem.

- Process outputs markdown log into a file or stream.
- I want a tool to watch that file, updating my markdown display.

Comment: There are editors that provide this function. [Atom](https://atom.io) with the [markdown-preview-plus](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-plus) package for example.

Comment: Thank you for your note.  Many editors will happily provide an editor with one pane of markdown.  Unfortunately, they will not provide a simple window of streaming markdown.   Different tools for different problems I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Personal trait:  I cannot put down a question.  Luckily the next experiment (after 40) worked!

- Open the file in Chrome (file://...)
- Use free "MarkDown Viewer" Chrome extension, enabled for file urls, to view.
- Use $4 LivePage Chrome extension, enabled for file urls, to reload page on each update.
- Open with line buffering in Python, `f = open('name', mode='w+', buffering=1)` or no buffering for byte files:  `f=open('name', mode='bw+', buffering=0)`
- Be happy.